# gsub extracting string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

My sample data is:

```
    c("2\tNO  PEMJNUM\t 2\tALTOGETHER HOW MANY JOBS\t216 - 217", 
"1\tREFERENCE PERSON 2\tSPOUSE 3\tCHILD 4\tOTHER RELATIVE (PRIMARY FAMILY & UNREL) PRFAMTYP\t2\tFAMILY TYPE RECODE\t155 - 156", 
"5\tUNABLE TO WORK  PUBUS1\t 2\tLAST WEEK DID YOU DO ANY\t184 - 185", 
"2\tNO  PEIO1COW\t 2\tINDIVIDUAL CLASS OF WORKER CODE\t432 - 433"
```

For each line, I'm looking to extract (they are variable names):

Line 1: "PEMJNUM"
Line 2: "PRFAMTYP"
Line 3: "PUBUS1"
Line 4: "PEIO1COW"

My initial goal was to gsub remove the characters to the left and right of each variable name to leave just the variable names, but I was only able to grab everything to the right of the variable name and had issues with grabbing characters to the left. (as shown here https://regexr.com/67r6j).

Not sure if there's a better way to do this!

Comment: Your regex test is invalid as you tested against string literals and not literal strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` in the following way:

```r
x <- c("2\tNO  PEMJNUM\t 2\tALTOGETHER HOW MANY JOBS\t216 - 217", 
 "1\tREFERENCE PERSON 2\tSPOUSE 3\tCHILD 4\tOTHER RELATIVE (PRIMARY FAMILY & UNREL) PRFAMTYP\t2\tFAMILY TYPE RECODE\t155 - 156", 
 "5\tUNABLE TO WORK  PUBUS1\t 2\tLAST WEEK DID YOU DO ANY\t184 - 185", 
 "2\tNO  PEIO1COW\t 2\tINDIVIDUAL CLASS OF WORKER CODE\t432 - 433")
sub("^(?:.*\\b)?(\\w+)\\s*\\b2\\b.*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "PEMJNUM"  "PRFAMTYP" "PUBUS1"   "PEIO1COW"
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m4Xgpl/1) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/I5X85x).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*\b)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches any zero or more chars (other than line break chars since I use `perl=TRUE`, if you need to match line breaks, too, add `(?s)` at the pattern start) as many as possible, and then a word boundary position
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more word chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `2` - a `2` digit
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - the rest of the line/string.

If there are always whitespaces before `2`, the regex can be written as `"^(?:.*\\b)?(\\w+)\\s+2\\b.*"`.